# File\Directory Security Permissions

Tags: delphi, file, permissions, directory

Have an annoying issue, and I dont essentially know where it comes from :(
So, the subject is:
When trying to check folders permissions from localhost (from actual filesystem) it (code attached below) works fine, but when application is launched from the network (eg: \*machinename*) it does not. **When I'm requesting ANY permission I always get Approval over the network, but can't create file, for example, because I dont have sufficient 
permission for it!**

```
iccFile_Security =
    class
        const
            FILE_READ_DATA        = $0001;
            FILE_WRITE_DATA       = $0002;
            FILE_APPEND_DATA      = $0004;
            FILE_READ_EA          = $0008;
            FILE_WRITE_EA         = $0010;
            FILE_EXECUTE          = $0020;
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES  = $0080;
            FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = $0100;
            FILE_GENERIC_READ     = (    STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ
                                      or FILE_READ_DATA
                                      or FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                      or FILE_READ_EA
                                      or SYNCHRONIZE
                                    );
            FILE_GENERIC_WRITE    = (    STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE
                                      or FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                      or FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
                                      or FILE_WRITE_EA
                                      or FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                      or SYNCHRONIZE
                                    );
            FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE  = (    STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE
                                      or FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                      or FILE_EXECUTE
                                      or SYNCHRONIZE
                                    );
            FILE_ALL_ACCESS       = (    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
                                      or SYNCHRONIZE
                                      or $1FF
                                    );
        strict private
        public
            class function check( _filename : String; _desiredAccess : DWORD                       ) : Boolean; overload;
            class function check( _filename : String; _desiredAccess : DWORD; out _failed : Boolean) : Boolean; overload;
    end;

implementation

{ iccFile_Security }

class function iccFile_Security.check( _filename: String; _desiredAccess: DWORD) :    Boolean;
var _failed : Boolean;
begin
    result := check( _filename, _desiredAccess, _failed) and not _failed;
end;

class function iccFile_Security.check( _filename : String; _desiredAccess : DWORD; out _failed : Boolean) : Boolean;
var Token       : DWORD;
    Status      : LongBool;
    Access      : DWORD;
    SecDescSize : DWORD;
    PrivSetSize : DWORD;
    PrivSet     : PRIVILEGE_SET;
    Mapping     : GENERIC_MAPPING;
    SecDesc     : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
begin
    Result := False;

    SecDesc     := nil;
    SecDescSize := 0;

    try
       GetFileSecurity( pchar( _filename),
                            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                         or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                         or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                         nil,
                         0,
                         SecDescSize
                       );

        SecDesc := GetMemory( SecDescSize);

        if not GetFileSecurity( pchar( _filename),
                                   OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                                or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                                or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                SecDesc,
                                SecDescSize,
                                SecDescSize
                              )
            then begin
                     _failed := true;
                     exit;
                 end;


        ImpersonateSelf( SecurityImpersonation);
        OpenThreadToken( GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, False, Token);

        if Token = 0
            then begin
                     _failed := true;
                     exit;
                 end;

        Mapping.GenericRead    := FILE_GENERIC_READ;
        Mapping.GenericWrite   := FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
        Mapping.GenericExecute := FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
        Mapping.GenericAll     := FILE_ALL_ACCESS;

        MapGenericMask( Access, Mapping);
        PrivSetSize := SizeOf( PrivSet);
        AccessCheck( SecDesc, Token, _desiredAccess, Mapping, PrivSet, PrivSetSize,         Access, Status);
        CloseHandle( Token);

        if _desiredAccess = Access
            then result := Status;
    finally
        FreeMem( SecDesc, SecDescSize);
    end;
end;
```

---

WORKS Correctly:

```
if not iccFile_Security.check( 'C:\temp\',     iccFile_Security.FILE_ALL_ACCESS)
        then ...
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
if not iccFile_Security.check( '\\testmachine\temp\',         iccFile_Security.FILE_ALL_ACCESS)
        then ...
```

Any comments\suggestions? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first suggestion is when you say "it doesn't work" or "I get an error" in a question, the **very** next thing you type is exactly what that expression means. [We can't read your mind from here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172661) or see your screen, and if you tell us what "it doesn't work" means, we don't have to guess.

Comment: Oops, forgot about that :) Updated.

Comment: Out of interest, why does any of this code exist? Isn't it just easier to create the file and if you get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` then you know that you don't have sufficient permissions. Why are you trying to replicate the rights checking that the system already does for you?

Comment: David, such approach is not suitable. There is no reason to create file and then delete it, if it was created. Wanna read permissions and read (retrivev) them correctly.

Comment: No, I don't mean that you should create a file and then delete it. I mean wait until you actually need to create a file and then try to create it. If it works you are good. If you get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` then you don't have sufficient rights. Why do you need to predict in advance whether or not an action will succeed. The usual result of that is programs that fail to attempt actions that would in fact succeed.

Comment: Need to predict in advance. It's very important in my case. And, of couse, I want to know why this code does not work over the network...

Comment: Well OK. I find it hard to imagine why that would be so, but I guess you know your problem and I don't. Looking at the code, the first thing I would do would be to add proper error checking for all the Windows API calls. It's pretty much pointless to proceed until you have done that.

Comment: Having said all that, testing security on a different machine is certainly something that I would expect to be quite tricky. It seems plausible to me that this approach would not be sufficient.

Comment: I don't see you doing any error-checking in this code. You call lots of API functions, only two of them have the potential to set `failed = True`. The others you just *assume* work fine. Even when you detect an error, you don't call `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong. Even if you don't report the error code externally, I'd still expect you to call it internally so you're not debugging blind.

Comment: In your first paragraph, you say that the difference between working and non-working code is where *your program* is launched from. It works when launched from a local disk, but fails when the EXE lives on a network share. Your example code says the difference is where *the tested file* lives, not your EXE file. Please be precise about what it is that fails and when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah. I've answered this one before -- network file security is an unreliable crap-shoot. (I dumped all of my code for doing so in favor of just checking to see if I could write a file in the dir.)

C.f., http://www.ureader.com/msg/16591730.aspx

Read the discussion about AccessCheck(); specifically:

> Even when performing AccessCheck(), you are doing an access check
>   against  an access token that is generated "locally", with the
>   security descriptor  associated with the object. When you directly
>   access the object on a remote  system, a network access token gets
>   generated on the remote system. This  network access token is used to
>   perform access check on the object to  determine whether access should
>   be granted or denied. The object could be  either a file or named pipe
>   or AD object.
>
> e.g. If the user is member of Administrators group on the remote
>   system,  when you directly access the object on a remote system, the
>   network access  token that gets generated on the remote system will
>   have Administrators  group and will allow access. Whereas, when you
>   call AccessCheck() with a  local access token, you will get different
>   results.

Comment: Wow, thx.  So what should I do? Any working workaround? Really dont want to create and delete files just to get in know if I can write to the destinated resource.

Comment: I don't think so. For Windows servers the problem comes down to retrieving the user's token from the network system and I don't think that's possible. For SAMBA servers -- Linux et al. -- there may not even be such a concept.

Comment: Meh.. :( So sad... Nevertheless, huge thanks for the explanation

Comment: This is exactly the sort of issue which leads me to take the view expressed in my comments to the question